# The 64-bit libuuid is not compatible and the 32-bit libuuid cannot be found when compiling

Tags: compiler-errors, redhat

I tried to compile a 32-bit program under 64-bit RH5 but encountered this problem:

> /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib64/libuuid.so when
>   searching for -luuid
>
> /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib64/libuuid.a when searching
>   for -luuid
>
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -luuid
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I did some research and I found a lot of RPM that can install the libuuid but they have different package names, so I am not sure which one to install actually.

Can anyone give me some idea?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please post the exact linker line you are using?

Comment: @Martinv.Löwis it is using Makefile and in the Makefile here is the line "MOD_LIBS = ... -luuid ..."

Comment: Still, when you run the makefile, it should print the exact compiler command line. Thinks like the precise name of the compiler binary, and -L options, matter for the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the 32-bit libuuid.  Look for a package with both 'uuid' and 'i386' in the name.

If it is not available from a repository you will need to compile libuuid yourself.  If you do this, make sure to point the compiler to the location of your self-compiled libuuid.so with the -L flag.